# Supply travisci with a database image

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

I just got started with a Travis CI script and I would like to supply my build with a current snapshot of the site (supplied mysql db).

How exactly can I do this and get Travis to import my image to the local database to run tests against?

Answer (score 2):

You can user `before_script` for setting the tables etc. Something like following:

```
services: mysql
before_script:
  - mysql < path/to/dump.sql
```